# How to force VueJs to show/hide element before/after loading large amounts of data into DOM?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

We've got an app which loads a lot of data into an interactive map.

The user can select data & some of it takes a while to load.

Our first approach was this:

```
<div v-show="loading" class="loading">Loading Data...</div>

methods: {
  loadData(data){
    this.loading = true
    // Load large amounts of data into map
    this.loading = false
  }
```

However the `loading` element wouldn't update until after the data had loaded into the map.

So I tried [Vue.nextTick](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick)

```
loadData(data){
  var self = this
  this.loading = true
  Vue.nextTick()
  .then(function () {
    // Load large amounts of data into map
    Vue.nextTick()
    .then(function () {
      self.loading = false
    })
  })
}
```

But this didn't work either. The `loading` element would not appear & the app would wait for the data to load.

The data is being loaded from 15MB of JSON & requires heavy computation/ iteration. For example users can concatenate or compare thousands of data points.

What is the correct way of doing this so the `loading` element is visible while the data is loading & disappears once it is loaded?

Comment: How's the data loaded? You could be blocking the main thread with heavy computation and preventing the browser from re-rendering. In which case you should consider using a web worker.

Comment: Have you tried `setTimeout()` instead of `$nextTick()` ?

Comment: May be obvious but did you make your property `loading` reactive by adding it in the data object: `data() { return { loading: false }}` ?

Comment: @HusamIbrahim - will look into web worker solution. @IVOGELOV - yes, tried `setTimeout()`. @SylvainF - yes, `loading` is in the data object.